# A TV show, from the 90's or 80's, very weird

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi

Does anyone remember a show, where:

- An alien girl lives with a family
- She comes from the moon
- She is looking for a new king because their king (a giant baby) is dying
- Her spaceship its a VW van
- They had a doorframe, yes a doorframe, that could open to other alternative universes or dimentions

Comment: Sounds fairly normal by the standards of 80s/90s cartoons.

Comment: very probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159776/i-need-help-remembering-a-very-obscure-tv-series

Answer (score 11):

I believe you are talking about "[The Miraculous Mellops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miraculous_Mellops_%28TV_series%29)". This was an Australian comedy in the very early 90's that ran for two seasons.

The first season describes what you are talking about, in that a race of children exist on the moon, and their "Grand Baby" leader is nearing the end of his life, and they send his mental abilities to Earth to find a new leader.

This goes awry, and they send two people in a ship disguised as a VW to Earth to straighten things out.

Comment: I think the doorframe that went to alternate universes (and also travel through time, IIRC) was in the second season, though.

Comment: @ConMan - Could be. I only ever saw one or two episodes somewhere, but the "grand baby" think stuck in my head for some reason.

Comment: Probably something to do with the fact that it actually was a giant talking baby.