# Obscure 80s-90s TV series with a spaceship Volkswagen and a giant space baby

Tags: story-identification, tv

Okay, I have a vague memory of a kids TV series that I caught when I was way too young to understand it, and now my brain is eating itself trying to remember what it was called.  Below you will find a list of all of the things that I remember about it to help identify it:

1. It may have been an American production, but I remember it had a different look and sound to it.  It was most likely a Canadian or British show, but it may have also been Australian (this one is the least likely to me, but I do not want to rule it out).
2. It had to have been made somewhere between 1988 and 1998.
3. It looked like it was aimed at the 12 to 15 year old demographic (but I'd widen this area to between 9 and 18 to be safe)
4. A giant space baby was absolutely involved (that is something I am certain of)
5. The space baby may or may not have worn biker gear
6. The space baby apparently held some leadership role with its species
7. It may have featured a Volkswagen van that was also a spaceship (Although I am iffy on that one)
8. I clearly remember a scene where an adult (who may have been a bad guy) tries to become the space baby by using his toothpaste.

Typing this all out I realize how insane it all must seem, but I am certain this thing exists.

Comment: The space baby was not a scaled up human baby, but rather an immobile fat guy...possibly in biker gear.  I also should have mentioned that it was live action.

Comment: My memory says baby, but that could just be the result of my child self at the time interpreting a fat immobile thing as a baby.

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way.  I understand how vague my list is, so your willingness to make suggestions is very heartening.

Comment: I have found it!!! You have saved my brain.  The Miraculous Mellops!  I have been saved from brain auto-cannibalism!

Comment: If you found it, you should write an answer to your question.

Answer (score 9):

This is [*The Miraculous Mellops*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miraculous_Mellops_(TV_series)) (1991), a scifi/comedy show produced by Film Australia.

You can see the flying Volkswagen-van spaceship below

And "The Grand Baby".